# How to convert a String to Object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have two model classes Employee and AdditionalDetails

```
class Employee{
  AdditionalDetails(this.uuid, this.additional_details);

  String uuid;
  String additional_details; 
}

class AdditionalDetails{
  AdditionalDetails(this.start, this.end, this.month);

  String start;
  String end;
  String month;

}

And I have a handler in which I am creating objects of AdditionalDetails and pushing into a list.


  List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>;
  String add1 = AdditionalDetails("start1", "end1", "dec").toString();
  String add2 = AdditionalDetails("start2", "end2", "jan").toString();
  list.add(1, add1);
  list.add(2, add2);
```

I am displaying these items in a list and on click of each item , I have to display other details in a dialog box.

I am able to get the uuid by iterating over the list but when doing **json.decode(additional_details)**, it is giving this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
```

How can I get the start, end and month properties from the additionalDetails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
class Employee {
  Employee(this.uuid, this.additionalDetails);

  String uuid;
  String additionalDetails;
}

class AdditionalDetails {
  AdditionalDetails(
    this.start,
    this.end,
    this.month,
  );

  final String start;
  final String end;
  final String month;

  @override
  String toString() => '$start $end $month';
}

final list = <Employee>[];
final add1 = AdditionalDetails("start1", "end1", "dec").toString();
final add2 = AdditionalDetails("start2", "end2", "jan").toString();
list.add(Employee('1', add1));
list.add(Employee('2', add2));
```

More cool way:

```
class Employee {
  Employee({
    @required this.uuid,
    @required this.additionalDetails,
  });

  final String uuid;
  final AdditionalDetails additionalDetails;

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Employee(
        uuid: json["uuid"],
        additionalDetails: json["additionalDetails"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "uuid": uuid,
        "additionalDetails": additionalDetails.toJson(),
      };
}

class AdditionalDetails {
  AdditionalDetails({
    @required this.start,
    @required this.end,
    @required this.month,
  });

  final String start;
  final String end;
  final String month;

  factory AdditionalDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      AdditionalDetails(
        start: json["start"],
        end: json["end"],
        month: json["month"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "start": start,
        "end": end,
        "month": month,
      };
}

final list = <Employee>[];
final add1 = AdditionalDetails(start: "start1", end: "end1", month: "dec");
list.add(Employee(uuid: '1', additionalDetails: add1));

final json = add1.toJson(); // Map<String, dynamic>
final startFromJson = json['start'];

final object = AdditionalDetails.fromJson(json); // AdditionalDetails
final startFromObject = object.start;
```

Comment: I have to say that this is not cool way. I suggest you should use built_value or freezed packages for serialization.

Comment: Thanks, @bcihan for giving the idea to use the package. I have encoded and decoded the json using jsonEncode and jsonDecode.

Comment: Ok, I made a few additions to my answer, check it out.

Comment: You can serialize and deserialize your models without encode or decode.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create an object out of string instead of jsondecode you should use toJson and fromJson function:

```
class AdditionalDetails{
  AdditionalDetails(this.start, this.end, this.month);

  String start;
  String end;
  String month;

  AdditionalDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    this.start = json['start'];
    this.end = json['end'];
    this.month = json['month'];

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){

    Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
    data['start'] = this.start;
    data['end'] = this.end;
    data['month'] = this.month;
    return data;

  }

}
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>;
String add1 = AdditionalDetails("start1", "end1", "dec").toJson();
String add2 = AdditionalDetails("start2", "end2", "jan").toJson();
list.add(1, add1);
list.add(2, add2);

final object = AdditionalDetails.fromJson(add1);
```